# Regex for strings not starting with "/*"

Tags: regex

What regex matches all strings except ones starting with a literal `/*`, meaning a slash (`U+002F`) followed by a star (`U+002A`)?

I’ve tried `^.*[^/\*]` but it doesn’t seem to work for me.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to filter out comments from something, since those might start anywhere and span multiple lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!/\*).*
```

This will match everything except if it starts with `/*`.

Or if you mean anything except `/` or `*`:

```
^[^/*].*
```

Comment: thanks will accept, would you mind telling me how to OR this with // (single line comment)? Which means doesn't start with /* or //

Comment: @smallB You can simply OR the lookahead: `^(?!/\*|//).*`.

Comment: `^(?!/[/*])` is all you need. If I were you, I’d be using “/x mode” to make it legible.  So prefix with `(?x)` or using the right pattern compilation flag.  That’s `Pattern.COMMENTS` in Java or just `/x` in many languages.

Comment: @tchrist It depends on what you want to do with the regex. If you want to capture or replace you need something for that. If you just want to test you're right. Unfortunately OP didn't tell which exactly is the use case.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is for matching strings that starts with a character other than `/` and `*` - stemmed from misreading the question. Ignore this.

```
^[^/*].*
```

`^` Beginning of string
`[^/*]` Any character other than `/` and `*`
`.*` more characters (

Comment: That's not correct; * is allowed as the first character, just not as the second after a /

Comment: @triplee Agreed, I misread the question as strings that starts with any character other than the characters `/` and `*` - question is now clear, thanks to the edits.

Answer (score 0):

that `.*` in the beginning is matching anything and everything. You just need to move your `not` block to the beginning:

```
^[^/*].*
```

Answer (score -1):

`^[^/*]` should be all you need:

```
$ echo -e "*red\n/green\nblue"
*red
/green
blue
$ echo -e "*red\n/green\nblue" | egrep "^[^/*]"
blue
```

If you definitely need to match lines with at lease two characters you can use `^[^/*].+`