# how to match any string but not a string that starts with slash?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

how to match any string but not a string that starts with a slash?

I'm using node js regex

that was my try but it didn't work

```
(?!\/s).*
```

Comment: `^[^\/]` tried this?

Comment: the regex should be `/^[^\/].*/`

Comment: Just `/^(?!\/)/.test(s)` should be enough. A lookahead will work here, not a lookbehind.

Comment: yes this is what I want @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Dupe of [Regex for strings not starting with “/*”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746744/3832970)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[^\/]` match everything except that starts with slash

`^[^\/].*` if you want to match the whole string

Comment: it matches the first char only

Comment: Then use `/^[^\/].*/`

Comment: Or `/^(?!\/)[^]*/` if you want to match 1) empty strings, too and 2) the strings may have line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `startsWith` function:

```
if(!str.startsWith('/')) // true for your case
```

Comment: I'm using a library that gives me event handler
 bot.onText( /regex/ , (msg, match) =>{ . . . 
so I want to capture any string that doesn't starts with /